# Convert language while transforming data from XML via XSL

Tags: java, xml, xslt, translation, hindi

I would like to convert English content of XML data into Hindi, on an html or doc using xsl in java.

Can this possibly be achieved ?

I have tried using locale but didn't not get any output.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your XSLT calls other Java methods to translate between English and Hindi then it is technically possible.

In case you expect and automatic translation, then the answer is: No.

A Locale just influences formatting of local specific things like dates, monetary values, numbers and the like.

Comment: "Well, if your XSLT calls other Java methods to translate between English and Hindi then it is technically possible."                                                                                   For this what i have to do can you please elaborate.

Comment: I believe that what Florian Frey is saying is: You will require a Java library that performs translation between English and Hindi.  Nothing in XSLT prevents your calling such a library; the problem will be finding one that works.

Comment: What I wanted to say is: It is not sufficient to specify a Locale, as a Locale is about formatting only. There's no built-in text recognition and translation mechanism in the Java Language itself nor in the standard libraries.